# Event not unbinding from document, in React.Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, mouseevent

I have a simple, but complex issue. I'm building a UI component in React.Js which uses knobs. The knobs can be turned from left to right (like a physical knob can), and will render the appropriate knob heading (North, South, etc.), based off how much the user dragged their cursor (all this happening in real time). So, I'm listening for the `onDragStart` event to get the initial heading (on the Y-axis) of the knob, and then adding the "mouse move" event to the document's event listeners, and taking the Y-axis movement from the "mouse move" event in comparison to the initial Y-axis from the `onDragStart` event to find the Delta from the drag, and then render the appropriate image. The problem comes when I try to unregister the events from the document (you know, good programming practices) based off the "mouse up" event (since the user will release the mouse button when reached their desired heading). Based off my attempt to print to the console whenever the "mouse up" event is heard by the browser, I've come to the conclusion that (since nothing is printed), the `mouseUp` event is not being heard, and as a result the `dragStop` method is not being run. I've pasted my code below (in JavaScript and JSX), and please don't hesitate to ask for a clearer explanation.

```
    var Knob = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return{season: this.props.season };
  },
  
  //Default properties
  getDefaultProps: function () {
    return { season: 1 };
  },
   
  //Start the drag functionality
  drag_start: function(data){

    // Store current 
    this.clientY = data.clientY;
    console.log("current location is: "+this.clientY);
    
    //Register 
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.drag);
    console.log("run");
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.dragStop);
    console.log("run");
  },
  
  drag: function(data){
    // Compare how far
    console.log("New location IS: "+data.clientY);
    var deltaY = data.clientY - this.clientY;
    
    // Do stuff with delta
    console.log("Difference is" + deltaY);
    
    // Store new current location
    this.clientY = data.clientY;
  },
  
  //Unregister the drag event from the document
  dragStop: function () {
    console.log("ran drag stop");
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.drag );
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.dragStop);
  },
  
 render: function(){
    return(
           <div>
            <img src = "../style/img/wood-bg.png" />
             <img src ={ '../style/img/Seasons/sprites_cut/'+this.state.season+'.png'} ref = "season" onDragStart = {this.drag_start} />
           </div>
    );//Ed
  } //end render function
}); //end knob class

React.render(<Knob />, mountNode);
```

Comment: You could have a boolean state property named `stoppedDragging` and in the listeners have: `if (!this.state.stoppedDragging) { /* do stuff... */ }`.

Answer (score 0):

When you add your event listeners, bind the function to `this` in order to maintain the scope:

```
//Register 
document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.drag.bind(this));
console.log("run");
document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.dragStop.bind(this));
console.log("run");
```

Otherwise the function of the event will be bound to `document`.

Comment: Hey, that kind of works, but now its running the DragStop function even when the mouse is still down